# Should I use "has X years old" or "is X years old"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-choice

Should I use 'has' or 'is'?

> 1. My son **has** 21 years old.
> 2. My son **is** 21 years old.

Comment: In Spanish, you would say, "Mi hijo tienes viente-cinco aÑos," which translated literally means "My son has 25 years," but which is understood to mean "My son is 25 years old."

Comment: In French it is the same way.  They have years, instead of being years old.

Comment: No, in Spanish you would say, "Mi hijo **tiene** veinticinco años.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To describe someone's age, height, weight, size, shape, and so on, we use the verb *to **be***.

So you should use ***is*** in your question, not <del>*has*</del>:

> My son **is** 21 years old.

You can think of this *"21 years old"* as an **[adjective phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase)**. *Adjectives* are words we use to describe things. You can also think of this *X years old* phrase the same way as *old* when you say *"He is old."* For example,

> *That man is very old. He is a professional cyclist!*
>   *How old is he?*
>   *He's 102 years old!*

Comment: +1 BUT *He's a hundred-and-two-year-old man*, singular *year*. OP should not ask Why, there's no reason, it just is.

Comment: @StoneyB Actually, there is a semi-consistent rule in English that when a noun (such as "year") is used in a modifier before a noun, it should be singular.

Comment: @andybalholm Quite so. But the rule is as far as I know completely unmotivated and arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

To express age, we use the verb `to be`, so

> Your son **is** 21 years old.

Other examples:

> How old **are** you?
>
> I **am** 39.